# Transmit data from pl sql to php file

Tags: php, variables, plsql

is there a posibility to transmit variables from pl sql to a php file without using HTML oder JavaScript?
I havent found a way yet. But I think there possibilitys. Thank you in forward for your answer.
little sidenote: its a procedure that gives the variable

Comment: Php can execute sql scripts and get the output. Maybe [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+oracle+connection&oq=php+oracle)